SSIS export SQL result to csv but the column order changed
I am trying to use a Data Flow Task to export a SQL query result into csv file. It's a very simple SQL. The column PTLASTUPDATEDDTTM is a DATETIME type. My SQL have to convert its format:
select rtrim([PTADDRESSIDPK]) as [PTADDRESSIDPK],
rtrim([PTADDRLINKIDPK]) as       [PTADDRLINKIDPK],
rtrim(      [PTPOSTALCODE]) as       [PTPOSTALCODE],
rtrim(      convert(varchar, [PTLASTUPDATEDDTTM], 105) + ' '+  convert(varchar, getdate(), 108)  ) as       [PTLASTUPDATEDDTTM],
rtrim(      [PTPerson]) as       [PTPerson] from Table_A

But after I put it into the SQL source. And set destination as Flat File, its column mapping messed up. The [PTLASTUPDATEDDTTM] become 1st column in the destination. How can I change this column back to its original position (the same position as the SQL query)? And my SQL used rtrim() because if I don't use it, the csv (use vertical bar | as column delimiter) will have spaces in each column. Is there any other way to get rid of redundant spaces in each column?



Delete the flat file destination and add it again in the package with the new mapping. SSIS is not forgiving when you are changing the source.

I found the issue. I used an existing csv as destination file. Then the order of columns are decided by that old existing csv.
